# how to use a dynamic variable as a key in retrieving table value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, variables

I am using below python to retrieve the value of month using dictionary, end up unable to use the variable as a key element in using as a key to retrieve the element of table. 
I would like to know how to use a dynamic variable as a key in accessing the table element.

months_dic = { 'Jan' : 1, 'Feb' : 2 , 'Mar' : 3, 'Apr' : 4, 'May' : 5, 'Jun' : 6, 'Jul' : 7, 'Aug' : 8, 'Sep' : 9, 'Oct' : 10, 'Nov' : 11, 'Dec' : 12 }
month = "oct"
print (months_dic['month'])

is giving below error
KeyError: 'monthi'

I am expected the print value should be 10.

Comment: There doesn't exist a key called 'month', but the value of your key is stored in the month variable. So you should do `months_dict[month] ` to get the key value from the dictionary. There are no single quotes required

Comment: That is because the key value is case-sensitive. You are looking for "oct" when the key value is actually "Oct" (Notice the capitalization)

Answer (score 1):

The value of your key is stored in the variable, and to use the value of the variable, you should not use quotes.

```
months_dict[month]
```